# Electric force vs. Magnetic force

Tags: electromagnetism

$E$, electric field $\to$ $H$, magnetic field

$D$, electric flux density $\to$ $B$, magnetic flux density

$D=\epsilon E$ $\to$ $B= \mu H$

Electric force calculation is based on electric field: $F=qE$

But...

Magnetic force calculation is based on not magnetic field($H$) but magnetic flux density($B$): $F=qv \times B$

What is the reason behind that? For magnetic force, why is magnetic flux density is used instead of magnetic field?

Comment: An electric field (like a magnetic field) is a vector, while a magnetic induction is a pseudovector (or rather a 2-form, or a skew-symmetric tensor). It turns out that the magnetic force, in absence of magnetic monopoles, arises through a pseudovector field

Answer (score 3):

"Flux" and "field" are common terms that are sometimes misused.
Properly, "B" ${\it is}$ the magnetic field. People misunderstand "H" as the magnetic field because it is more easily defined in terms of free currents using Ampere's Law.

However, properly "flux" refers to the integral over an area of the magnetic field, B:

$$\Phi_B \equiv \int\vec B\cdot d\,\vec a$$

In conclusion, both the electric force on a charge and the magnetic or Lorentz force on it are due to the fields.

Comment: Sorry I should have written flux density not flux. I edited my question.

Comment: The similarity between $D = \epsilon E$ and $B = \mu H$ causes endless confusion. The fact is that $E$ and $B$ are the true fields, while $D$ and $H$ include the response of materials: dielectrics which can be polarized and therefore have a field $P$, and permeable materials which can be magnetized and have a magnetization $M$. Unfortunately these two response fields have opposite signs in the constitutive equations that relate the fundamental fields $E$ and $B$ to the derived fields.